# How to set autoFocus for fluent UI Dropdown control

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-teams

I want to set up autoFocus for fluent UI dropdown control there is the property for TextField as autoFocus and we can set it as true or false. but there is no such property for Dropdown control.

So is there any way to set a focus for dropdown control?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi Dinesh. Are you using <DropDown> instead a class component or functional component?

Answer (score 0):

To begin, it's not obvious when a `<Dropdown>` is focused. So, I suggest adding this style to your .scss file for debugging purposes:

```
:global {
  *:focus, div:focus, span:focus{
    border: green 3px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f90 !important;
  }
}
```

Example of a focused Dropdown:

[image]

Assuming you are using class components. In your class component that adds Dropdown, add the _dropdown variable right after the class definition:

```
export default class SAMPLE_CLASS extends React.Component<SAMPLE_CLASSProps>  {
  private _dropdown = React.createRef<IDropdown>();
```

In the same component, find your Dropdown and add the componentRef property, pointing to your `_dropdown` variable:

```
<Dropdown
   label="Site LOB"
   componentRef = {this._dropdown}
   ...
/>
```

Now that you have the reference to the dropdown, you can set focus to in either `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`:

```
public componentDidMount(){
  this._dropdown.current.focus();
}

// Try this if you need to focus after each update
public componentDidUpdate(){
  this._dropdown.current.focus();
}
```